# How to add a small stripe video background using html like kidscodeacademy.com?

Tags: html, video, background, web-deployment

I need to add a full screen video as background but in a html div section on home page. [This website](http://kidscodeacademy.com) has nice stripe video. I exactly like that video. How can I add such effect over the video.
Note: I have web-m format video file.

Comment: What have you do so far? Have you some code to show us?
Basically they have add a container around the video with a background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know about your specific needs , but for a basic understanding of this header fullscreen background video I can give you a link where you can learn how to make it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O_Bw1_0u1P8

Please let us know , if there is any problem .

Comment: Helpful video, I made it. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

Video Background , Put your content inside the container.
https://jsfiddle.net/ashwinshenoy/rh7n5d0g/1/

Hope this Helps buddy!

```
<div class="video_div">
    <video class="video is-playing" autoplay="" muted="" loop="" poster="assets/video/thumb.jpg">
       <source src="http://ak3.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/5949803/preview/stock-footage-little-children-playing-football-at-school-k.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video><!--video tag end-->
    <div class="video-overlay" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://d3k5xyayaartr5.cloudfront.net/_assets/pattern-overlays/patterns/black-dots.png&quot;);"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <!--your content here-->
    </div><!--container end-->
</div><!--video_div end-->

<style>
  // Video Div
  .video_div {
     overflow: hidden;
     padding: 230px 0 0;
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     height: 87vh;
   }

   @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
     .video_div {
       padding: 230px 0;
       width: 100%;
     }
   }

   .video_div video {
     position: absolute;
     min-width: 100%;
     min-height: 100%;
     width: auto;
     height: auto;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
     -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
     transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
     z-index: -200;
   }

   .video-overlay {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     right: 0;
     pointer-events: none;
     opacity: .5;
     background-repeat: repeat;
   }
 // Video Div End
 </style>
```